# http_basic_authenticate_with not showing authentication prompt and outputting error to server log. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working through the Ruby on Rails 'Getting Started' guide. In section 9 we attempt to add basic authentication to the controllers to disallow actions such as updating a blog article and deleting blog comments.

The guide says to use the following code at the top of the article_controller class

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]
```

Doing so and then attempting to update an article (or any of the blocked actions) causes seemingly nothing to happen on the browser (no authentication prompt) however when viewing the output from the rails server command in the terminal I get the following request data repeated until I close the page:

```
Started GET "/articles/3/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-04 15:41:39 +0100
Processing by ArticlesController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007fc5d915e6f8@/Users/Ben/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71> rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have followed the guide to the letter thus far with no issues. I have noticed a number of similar questions to this online with no answers. None of them included the output from the server so I'm hoping this might give a clue as to the cause.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you by chance enter incorrect info? The browser may be retrying the incorrect info.  You may want to try Firefox with the Firebug extension, which will be useful even if it doesn't help with this particular case.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by incorrect information? The http_basic_authenticate_with code is copied directly from the tutorial and the popup authentication box does not show itself when I try and load the page. I use firebug but could you tell me what I should be looking out for.

Comment: When you have Firebug activated, check the "Net" panel, it will show you the request and response headers.  Perhaps that will help you figure out what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I've faced problems due to mistakes in the rails's getting started guides. I often use the following code to the http basic auth:

```
before_filter :require_http_basic_auth, :except => [:index, :show]

def require_http_basic_auth
  # code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following question addresses a similar problem [rails authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479251/rails-authenticate-or-request-with-http-basic).

Check the answer to this question. It might help you understand what is exactly happening.